# How to add a number somewhere in a vector and move following numbers one spot?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, move, shift

I have a vector with 7 slots. I want to add a number between slot 0 and 1 and move the following numbers one slot.

For example I have the numbers 2, -5, 14, 21, -7, 0, 0 and want to add the number 10 between slot 0 and 1 (making it the new slot 1) and move the following numbers so that the result is 2, -10,-5, 14, 21, -7, 0.

This is my code so far but I don't know why it does nothing:

```
        int[] nbr = new int[7];
        int length = 7;
        
        nbr[0] = 2; nbr[1] = -5; nbr[2] = 14; nbr[3] = 21; nbr[4] = -7; nbr[5] = 0; nbr[6] = 0;
        
        
        for (int k = 0; k > 1 && k < length; k++) {
            nbr[k] = nbr[k-1];
```

What is wrong and how do I complete the code to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this? It looks like Java, C# or C++ but you create an array not a vector. Though in any of those, nbr[-1] isn't legal.

Comment: It's java, where do you see nbr[-1]?

Comment: You're right, although the for loop starts at k = 0 and so would set nbr[0] to nbr[0-1] it doesn't do anything because of the k>1 test and so stops immediately